# CLion run configuration Qt project on Windows, Linux, Mac

Tags: qt, clion

I am setting up Qt using CLion and build project successfully.
But the problem comes when I try to run it, which it does not run because it can't find the Qt Library.

When using QtCreator, I don't need to setup anything to run Qt project (it does automatically). So, how QtCreator run the project? So I can achieve it on CLion?

Already set PATH to Qt bin, but it does not work.

Comment: From your question it is not clear which step does not work. With CLion you must have a CMake project.
Maybe you can start here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: The building system is working properly. But when hit run, the project is not run.

Comment: This is not really helping, if you're not more precise than that I'm not sure anyone can do anything to help you.